# Laravel: How to access ModelFactory data inside a migration

Tags: php, laravel

I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve what I'm about to describe below.
The code below is not my exact code, but it gives an idea of what I'm looking for, and I don't want to expose the original.
I have few ModelFactory data created inside a test file, I and I would like to access those data inside a migration file, which I will manually run from the test class `$this->artisan('migrate', ['--path' => 'database/migrations/2022_11_17_150008_back_fill-data.php']);`

The code in the migration performs some data cleaning inside the database, and I have created a unit test that generates fake data. I then utilize the logic from the migration to verify that everything is working.

```
public function testBackfilldata()
{
  $user = User::factory()->create(['name' => 'hello']);

  // Call the migration file to the DB clean. Let's say we change all the names to start with a Uppercase
    $this->artisan('migrate', ['--path' => 'database/migrations/2022_11_17_150008_back_fill-data.php']);z

 // Then check if the names has been updated after running the migration manually.
   $this->assertTrue($user->contains('name', 'Hello');
  
}
```

I could use a class or something to host the logic and just call the class inside the migration as well as in the test, but I want to know if it is achievable by use the approach described earlier.

**When I run this code, the migration doesn't see the data created from the test unit.**

Comment: Sorry, I am confused, your issue is that you run the migration programmatically and it does not see the `User::factory()->create()` that was run before? Like, it cannot find or see the user it was created? If that is the case, can you run `dump(User::count());` inside the migration and make sure the user is there? You need to debug a little bit more and make 100% sure that the user is been created and the migration is ignoring it, maybe, due to a query filtering.

Comment: Hi @matiaslauriti that's correct. I dumped the users inside the migration and it is returning empty.

Comment: Are you using the same connection inside the migration?